# close div when clicking button inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that loads information from another page when someone clicks on a thumbnail image on the same page.

Currently, when a person clicks on a thumbnail image, the div #dynamic at the top of the page will load and display information from another page. I want to be able to allow users to click on a close button which i have given a class button_close for them to close the div instead of clicking anywhere within it. The button is being displayed within the #dynamic div as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('nav.main > a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dynamic").load($(this).attr('href') + " .product_content", ()=>{ window.scrollTo(0, 0) }).fadeIn('slow');
   });
      $(".button_close").click(function(){
          $(".product_container").html ('');
      });
  });
```

Comment: add e.stopPropagation() to the '.button_close' click handler

Comment: "*when the person clicks anywhere within the DIV, the div will close*" what div?  Please see [MCVE]

Comment: @Pete Thank you for your feedback. I have made it clearer hopefully.

Comment: @Cabon please see the link in my comment - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without a MCVE the question will be closed

Comment: do `$(document).on('click', '.button_close', function()) {$('.target').html('');})` - I think your code is fine, but where it's dynamically created it isn't firing because it's outside the document delegation scope. Adding the document in front means it searches the document when you click and when clicked element has id/class of whatever, then fire the function

Answer (score 1):

Since your close_button is being generated dynamically, you can use the following

```
$('body').on('click', '.button_close', function(){
    $('#dynamic').html('');
});
```

A simple example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
function loadDiv() {
    $('#dynamic').html('<p>Some content loaded from another page</p><div class="button_close">Close Me</div>');
}

$('body').on('click', '.button_close', function(){
    $('#dynamic').html('');
});
</script>

<div id="dynamic"></div><br><br>
<button onclick="loadDiv()">Load Div</button>

</body>
</html>
```